# What to pass into tkinter find_enclosed

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to check out what objects (in this case, arcs) exist next to my currently selected objects. I thought I could do so using `event.widget.find_enclosed(coords)` with `coords` representing a tuple with 4 integers. However, every time I've tried to pass in the tuple I keep receiving this error:

`TypeError: find_enclosed() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'y1', 'x2', and 'y2'`

Full code below:

```
import tkinter as tk
import time
import numpy

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=500, height=200, bg='black')
canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

# apply bold to line
def bold(event):
    # initial boldness
    # find arc user meant
    id = event.widget.find_closest(event.x,event.y)[0]
    # retrieve arc tag
    tag = canvas.gettags(id)[1]
    print(tag)
    print(type(tag))
    # bold arc
    canvas.itemconfigure(id,width=5)
    # redraw canvas
    canvas.update()
    # give time to make each drawing piecemeal
    time.sleep(.5)

    current_coords = numpy.array(canvas.coords(id))
    next_coords_additive = numpy.array([arc_width,0,arc_width,0])
    next_coords = current_coords + next_coords_additive

    # grab data for next arcs
    next_arc_data = event.widget.find_enclosed(tuple(next_coords))

#     code to find the and bold the next available arc

# each bounding box is 100 x 100
class Box():
    def __init__(self, coords):
        # give the class a tag for tkinter to find later
        self.tag = 'box{}'.format(id(self))

        # make each arc
        self.arcs = [
            # arc 1
            canvas.create_arc(coords, start=0, extent=90, outline="white", style="arc", tag=(self.tag, 1)),
            # arc 2
            canvas.create_arc(coords, start=90, extent=90, outline="white", style="arc", tag=(self.tag, 2)),
            # arc 3
            canvas.create_arc(coords, start=180, extent=90, outline="white", style="arc", tag=(self.tag, 3)),
            # arc 4
            canvas.create_arc(coords, start=270, extent=90, outline="white", style="arc", tag=(self.tag, 4))
        ]

        # allow each arc to be bolded
        self.bind()

    def bind(self):
        # apply binding to every arc in box
        for arc in self.arcs:
            canvas.tag_bind(arc, "<Button-1>", bold)

# coordinates are (x,y) of upper left corner, and then (x,y) of lower left corner
# use numpy array for vector addition
coords = numpy.array([0, 0, 100, 100])


# use box width to calculate grid indice
box_width = coords[2] - coords[0]
# grid indice to move around
grid_indice = box_width/2

# use arc width for width of 1 component
# 4 components in 1 box
arc_width = box_width/2

# make desired size of grid (width, height)
size=[6,4]

for i in range(size[1]):
    # keep adding 1 grid indice to the y as you move down
    coords = coords + numpy.array([0, 0 + grid_indice, 0, 0 + grid_indice])

    for j in range(size[0]):
        # keep adding 1 grid indice to the x as you move to the right
        box_coords = coords + numpy.array([0 + grid_indice*j, 0, 0 + grid_indice*j, 0])

        # create variables to check parity
        even_row = i%2 == 0
        odd_row = not even_row
        even_column = j%2 == 0
        odd_column = not even_column

        # only draw a box on the same parity of i and j
        # that is: on an odd row (i), only draw on odd column (j) values
        if even_row & even_column:
            Box(tuple(box_coords))
        elif odd_row & odd_column:
            Box(tuple(box_coords))


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Read [Tkinter.Canvas.find_enclosed-method](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.find_enclosed-method)

Answer (score 0):

Don't pass a tuple, pass four distinct coordinates. Assuming that `next_coords` contains four coordinates, you can use the unpacking operator `*` to unpack your list of coordinates:

```
next_arc_data = event.widget.find_enclosed(*next_coords)
```

Comment: Thanks. I used the tuple but kept receiving () or an empty set. When I broadened the coordinators to just be (0,0,1000,1000), I started receiving data. So are the args to pass in x1, y1, x2, y2 relative to the canvas, where x1 and y1 are the upper left point, and x2 and y2 are the lower right point?

Comment: @ChristinaZhou: yes, they represent a region of the canvas, so they must be in canvas coordinates.

Comment: Odd. I found that the method `find_enclosed` is very literal, and I always need to make the bounding box slightly bigger than my event. That is, if my event exists in 100,50,200,150, I need to pass in 99,49,201,151, for it to find it...

Comment: @ChristinaZhou: I don't know what you mean by "event exists in 100,50,200,150". Events have a single x/y coordinate, not a range of coordinates. But yes, it is very literal. The item must be completely enclosed by the given coordinates. There is `find_overlapping` if you want to find objects that are only partially within the given region.

Comment: Sorry, I meant object, not event.